# Persist tokens for third party user-interaction RESTful service strategies. (Amazon AdApi)

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, openid-connect, access-token, amazon-advertising-api

I'm developing an `API` for a standalone `SPA` that is deployed in a static server. In my proposal architecture design, the `SPA` client accesses my API server by using the `access token` issued by my own implemented `identity Server` (`API` and `Identity Server` are separate servers).

`API server` needs to fetch data from `third party API` (in detail, it is `Amazon Ads API`). The third-party API is protected by an `access token` issued by its `identity server` (`OAuth2`). The situation is, each user has its own access token to access third-party API.

My challenge is how my API server persists the third-party `access token` and `refresh token` in a secure and effective way.

Notes: For Amazon, the `access token` expiration is for 1 hour, and the `refresh token` is for 30 days.

In my view, my API server is like the trusted middle man to fetch data from third-party API for `SPA`. Third-party API tokens are hidden from the `SPA` client.

Now I just implement to get third-party `access token` and `refresh token` stored in the database by my own `access token` `sub` claim. Then I will implement a distributed cached for improved performance. I asked if my design is a good pattern so that my efforts are valuable.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to not handle tokens in the browser, instead, handle it all in the browser and just use a session cookie between the SPA and the backend.

This video is a good resource for how to handle tokens in a SPA application:

[alert‘OAuth 2 0’; // The impact of XSS on OAuth 2 0 in SPAs](https://youtu.be/lEnbi4KClVw)